# Update a record by Primary Key or by Unique Key

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

About best practices on designing stored procedures, should a stored procedure updating a record in a table use the Primary Key to identify the record to be updated, or the Unique Key?

The Unique Key seems like a lot of additional parameters to send in and I can't think of a situation where the Primary Key wouldn't be known.

Comment: Why is this tagged Oracle and T-SQL? What is `WorkStudyID`? A primary key _is_ unique. The answer is effectively, _"it depends"_ and _"they're as good as identical anyway"_ so voting to close. PS I often don't know the PK in a procedure.

Comment: Show me a Primary Key that is not Unique

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question bears 2 different aspects.

- The goal: what you want to achieve is to update a given row. Any means allowing you to reach this point is good; in other terms, if the unique key, the primary key or any other combinaison of columns not listed under any unicity constraint would be ok then you might use it.
- The performances: as any other query you really want to go fast and straight to the point. What does it mean? It means that you have to chose the most efficient filter in you where clause. You can measure this by:

1/ the size of the index you are using: choose the smallest one (column size for instance)

2/ the not null attribute of the column of the index you are using: (if your engine allows unique indexes on nullable columns) choose preferably an index that is placed on a NOT nullable column.

3/ the tablespace of the index: you could also see if there is a special storage for an index rather than another, that would improve performances (mounted indexes...)

4/ the column type: usually small numbers are faster to parse than texts (apologize not having sources for that, take it with care)

I can't think of more now, but I'm pretty sure other people will complete the list.

Cheers.

Comment: It seems to me to be a lot of additional effort having to pass in 6 fields in order to update a record. That also seems like it would be a performance impact since this table can have a few million rows.

Comment: well, depends of the size of the 6 fields. Do you actually have a unique index on these fields??

Answer (score 2):

By "unique key" I assume you mean "business key". A business key is good to use as the parameters to a stored procedure if you had a database that is loosely synchronized from some external source.

Let's say you received a flat file from another company to order products, activate a service, start a process, or something. They probably don't know the primary keys, and things may be requested by name: (Company X, Service Y, Activate) you invoke your stored proc based by the unique Company name, unique service name, unique state. Sure, you might say the remote system should use the ids, but that is sometimes out of your control.

Another example: replication performed at an application level. The sequences may be out of sync between the two dbs, so referring to a remote record would be safer by a business key.

Comment: I suppose so, it's the fields that uniquely ID a record. We do know the primary key of the table, so it wouldn't be hard to get and would also seem to simplify the procedure calls. I'm wondering if this would impact our ability to use an ORM. I know some ORM's can do it via a unique key, but they appear to prefer primary keys.

Comment: I look at it this way: the pk id doesn't have meaning in itself. It acts as unique identifier for a record (a reference). It makes things easier. A sales territory defined by a unique (COUNTRY, STATE) can have a TERRITORY_ID as a reference (pk). It only has meaning internally. Externally, the COUNTRY-STATE pair is how things are referenced  ("Who is the rep for US-FL territory?") So long as things are self-contained, pk is easiest and makes sense, but that can break pretty quickly when dealing with external systems and data sources. Then business keys are better suited for the service apis.